# Git refusing push (behind remote counterpart)

Tags: git, github

There are quite a few questions on this subject, but they all seem to refer to when there are remote changes. That's not the case for me.

```
$ git push repo master
...
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart.

$ git fetch repo master
$ git diff repo/master
<single commit I've done locally>
```

Yes, `git pull` will allow me to push, but as I need to do it more or less every time something is wrong.

**Edit:**

Following Rup's comment I checked how it looked in `gitk --all`, and it looked like my remote was diverting. So, that's weird.

[image: Image from gitk --all]

Checking to see if I have that commit locally:

```
$ git branch -r --contains 48673b311730fdfcf71b0e5776f6180c5173df42
  origin/master
$ git branch --contains 48673b311730fdfcf71b0e5776f6180c5173df42
```

So, apparently I have a commit remotely, in a repo only I can access, that I don't have locally. I only use one computer, that commit could not come from anywhere else than this computer and me. I'm confused.

**Edit 2:**
So, following Javabrett's answer I ventured into reflogs.

```
d022f6d HEAD@{144}: pull bt master:
41a6f50 HEAD@{145}: pull bt master: checkout 41a6f50f7e3e96723f0d1c222205645d78a504db
48673b3 HEAD@{146}: commit: Added commented out urls to .env
14948e3 HEAD@{147}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
14948e3 HEAD@{148}: pull bt master: checkout 14948e3c4dd014bb5af7293fdee6772a9e605b6f
```

Where bt is the shared repo. My best guess, I've pushed to my private repo, but pulling down from the shared repo I rebase onto bt/master, and the original commit "disappears". Pushing to the private again will trigger a refusal, because the history doesn't sync. That about right?

Comment: It sounds like your changes have already been pushed into the remote.  `git pull` should simply fast forward.

Comment: Try `gitk --all` to see the exact relationship between your local and remote branches

Comment: Post a log of the most recent commits for local and remote.

Comment: Updated question after checking `gitk --all`, I'm confused to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gitk` view is a little small, so a bit of guesswork here, and doesn't contain commit-hashes or the current local `HEAD` or commit following "Removed ads from main layout" - is it a commit with comment "Added commented out urls to .env" or something completely different?  Either way it doesn't have commit hash `48673b3`.

Your `--contains` test is helpful.  You should also run `git reflog` and `grep` or search for `48673b3`.  This might show you when your local `HEAD` did point to `48673b3`, and what happened immediately or sometime after that.

The most likely thing is that via a direct command, or some tool, that you have rebaseed or squashed or amended the commit that is at `remotes/origin/master` in your local repo.  Or maybe you reset the date/time or author.  Git now sees this as an independent line of development - you should never rebase or squash into a commit that you've already pushed somewhere, again if that is what has happened.

Your `git reflog` might show something like this for example:

```
20fa43d HEAD@{0}: commit (amend): Added commented out urls to .env
48673b3 HEAD@{1}: commit: Added commented out urls to .env
e039c6c HEAD@{2}: commit: Updated backend variables to new test server.
```

If so, the (amend) tells you what went wrong - you would have re-written local history in that case, and you can no longer do a fast-forward push of this branch.  If that is the case, you can fix it with a rebase (maybe do this on a temp branch first):

```
git rebase --onto origin/master origin/master
```

Depending on what changed in your local history, you may get a merge conflict to resolve for the amended commit in your local.  After that you will have re-written any local commits so that they agree with the remote history, and you should be able to perform a fast-forward push.

**Question Edit 2 answer update:**

With the information on the other, upstream remote, the rebase on that and the reflog, it is reasonably clear what occurred.

The same change you made in `48673b3` and pushed to `origin/master` was also contained in another commit, either on its own or mixed-in with other changes, made by you or someone else and pushed to `upstream/master` (`bt/master` for you).  When you `git pull`ed from upstream, Git will have created a merge commit.  While it doesn't show in the reflog, you pulled and then rebased previously at `HEAD@{148}`/`HEAD@{147}`, so it's reasonable to assume that you have done so again sometime after `HEAD@{144}`, attempting to return to a linear-history, removing the merge commit.  You ran `git rebase` without `--keep-empty`, and when `48673b3` was replayed on-top of `bt/master`, there was nothing to do, so that commit was discarded, the default behaviour of rebase.

`origin/master` has now diverged from your local repo, being one commit `48673b3` ahead of the youngest common parent, which might be `14948e3`.  Git won't allow you to push (without `-f` force) - even if the tree hashes might be identical, the commit histories have diverged.

Some advice on workflows:

1) If you prefer rebasing and a linear history to having merge-commits (fair enough), then always stick to it.  Run `git fetch ...` and `git rebase ...`, never run `git pull` (fetch and merge) or `git merge`, or if you must, run them with the `--ff=only`, so they only run when you don't have any newer commits in your local.  Consider setting config `pull.ff=only` and `merge.ff=only` to enforce this in-case you forget them on the command-line.  With this in-place, unless you explicitly say otherwise, you'll never get to a non-linear state with upstream, you will always be reminded to `git rebase bt/master`.

This won't actually fix your problem, but it is best to avoid mixing merging/rebasing strategies.  If your strategy is to rebase and you accidentally create a merge, reset to your newest local commit and try again.

2) If you work with and push to two remote repos, one of which changes (upstream), and you are rebasing, sooner or later you are going to hit this problem and need to determine that your local is now "newest" and force-push to your private `origin/master`.  Rebasing a branch that has already been pushed to a remote will always eventually come unstuck - rebasing (or squashing or amending) are ways of rewriting-history, so the histories will always diverge.  If you are using `origin/master` simply as a "write-only" remote backup for your code, get used to running `push -f` to overwrite it (of course you need to know that this is correct or you will lose commits), or better still, just `push origin HEAD:``date -u +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`` to give you non-conflicting refs that you can later discard.  If you are using `origin` for something more complex then you will need to be aware of issues you will have when rebasing to upstream.

Comment: While I don't fully understand my reflogs, this answer is close enough for accepting. I've realized that it has to do with rebasing, and that's not unexpected. Feel free to comment on my second edit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to pull with rebase option.

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

than:

```
git push
```

Comment: Actually tried this yesterday, but it's unclear to me why this would make a difference.

Comment: Take a look at this reference: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html